# Need help me ID this file structure, and if so any way to decode it?

Tags: python, r, file, encryption, encoding

So I’m working with 25 years (~1100 files) of data from precipitation recorders saved in .hobo format.

The goal is to eventually save all records in one query-able database without using HOBOware software.  I’m just looking for ideas. I prefer working in R, but python is an option too. (This is a student project)

P.S. Sorry for the picture of a screen, but I’m not sure how else to share these special characters.  I can include a file if that helps.
[image]

Comment: is nothing in there? https://www.onsetcomp.com/files/manual_pdfs/12730-AD%20HOBOware%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf  there seem to be several ways/formats to export the data.

Comment: Not without their software.  My goal is to automate the process, and unfortunately I was just handed ~1100 .hobo files, so I don’t really have a choice about it